# Mathematical word for geometrical object?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polygons

Is there a mathematical word to designate the concept of a geometrical object like:

- square
- cube
- tesseract
- N-dimensional cube
- circle
- sphere
- hypersphere
- regular and non-regular polygons
- regular and non-regular polyhedrons
- ...

What is the common word to designate all these objects ?

Comment: Are you talking about manifolds?

Comment: [Polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) include all objects you mentioned except the circle, sphere and hypersphere.

Comment: And is there a word less generic than manifold to designate polytopes+n-spheres ?

Comment: They're rather different beasts to be honest. The polytopes are piecewise linear manifolds, where as the n-spheres are smooth differentiable manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all compact subsets of suitable $\mathbb R^n$. I would call them manifolds in a broad sense, considering both the cases "manifold with corners"-"manifold without corners" (but with boundary).